# Create unix socket inside of Alpine container to connect Gunicorn with Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, gunicorn

I'm moving my `Django` application (same as described [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dajngo-with-nginx-gunicorn-aaf8431dc9e0)) from local machine to `Docker` container.
I'm redirecting users that come to port `80` from Nginx to `Gunicorn` via `unix:run/gunicorn.sock` It works on my local machine, but I7m not sure how to describe this action in `Dockerfile`.
Right now I'm doing it this way, but it won't works...

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10

ADD mediadbin/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps postgresql-dev build-base python3-dev gcc jpeg-dev nginx zlib-dev\
    && python -m venv /env \
    && /env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip \
    && /env/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt \
    && runDeps="$(scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /env \
        | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r apk info --installed \
        | sort -u)" \
    && apk add --virtual rundeps $runDeps \
    && mkdir run/gunicorn.sock \
    && mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled \
    && apk del .build-deps


COPY ./config/mediadbin /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mediadbin


ADD mediadbin /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 5432
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 80


CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "unix:run/gunicorn.sock", "--workers", "3", "mediadbin.wsgi:application", "--name", "mediadbin"]
```

Also it won't throw an Error or somthing like that, so I'm not sure what is wrong...

- I'm able to run `Gunicorn` without `Nginx` via port 8000 in my container when I edit a little bit the script above

Comment: If you want to run both nginx and gunicorn, you would typically do this with two different containers (and use a shared volume to make the socket visible in both locations; or just use a tcp socket instead).

Comment: isn't the first solution too difficult when I can insert both to one container?
With the second one you mean bind gunicorn to some port?

Comment: You're already binding gunicorn to some sort of port (in this case, a Unix socket; but you could just as easily use a TCP socket). Using two containers is often simpler to set up, and it's absolutely simpler to manage (e.g., you can upgrade or reconfigure nginx without restarting your web service), but that's just my advice and you're welcome to solve your problem  in the way that works best for you.

Comment: I did the TCP socket forwarding settings in Nginx and it worked nice! thank you